# sum a state and event value

Tags: reactjs, math, react-props

I want to add a state and an event input value.
This is like state = 2, input value = 1, the result i expect it is 3.
But the result is not what i expect, the result is 21.
I had tried `parseInt()`, `parseFloat()`, `pkp[index].capaian.value + value.value`, but all of them fail. The result is still `string` 21, some of them `undefine`.
Any help ??

```
handleChange4 = (question, value) => {
const pkp = [...this.state.pkp];
const index = pkp.indexOf(question);
pkp[index] = { ...question };
pkp[index].capaian = pkp[index].capaian + value; //this math summary
this.setState({ pkp });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the answer

```
handleChange4 = (question, value) => {
const pkp = [...this.state.pkp];
const index = pkp.indexOf(question);
pkp[index] = { ...question };
pkp[index].capaian =
  (isNaN(parseInt(pkp[index].capaian)) ? 0 : parseInt(pkp[index].capaian)) +
  (isNaN(parseInt(value)) ? 0 : parseInt(value)); //this math summary
pkp[index].capaian = String(pkp[index].capaian);
this.setState({ pkp });
};
```